# Can an interface have a templated method name?

Tags: c#, templates, interface

I know the answer is probably no, but would still like to confirm.
Can an interface have variable method name? something like

```
Interface IVariableMethodName //something similar to <T>
{
   void T(int param);
   void T(string param);
}
```

I have some classes which would require function overload for couple functions with exactly the same parameter but different name and have different functionality. Is there a better way to do so instead of making bunch interfaces with almost the same content except method name?

Edited: an example

```
class Adder
{
    public int Add(int a, int b){}
    public float Add(float a, float b){}
    public decimal Add(decimal a, decimal b){}
}


class Subber
{
    public int Sub(int a, int b){}
    public float Sub(float a, float b){}
    public decimal Sub(decimal a, decimal b){}
}
```

What I am trying to do is similar to the examples with the only difference that the return type is the class itself. And the methods have very different functionality.

Comment: How would you implement that? `class MyClass : T` ?!

Comment: @Mihai well idk if the intellisence is smart enough to do such thing.... but it looks like its not that hard to make the compiler understand.

Comment: How about delegates? Same signature different implementations...

Comment: @BionicCode um... i am actually trying to find a way to avoid missing some of the overloads in some classes...and i dont want to have to search through all the classes when i add in a new overload..am wishing the compiler would help me out on that

Comment: @Steve: why does the method name even matter? Please show a complete example of how you would use such a feature, were it to exist. Maybe that will help make clearer why you feel the suggestion to use delegates doesn't work for you, and/or could lead to a solution that is actually possible.

Comment: @PeterDuniho demostration example provided. The functions have very different functionality, so the name matters.

Comment: Please elaborate on your example. Show how an interface would fit into that. Are you trying to create an interface that would include all three methods? Is there some reason that it is not feasible or desirable for you to declare a more general interface, where it's implemented by each specific type through delegation? I.e. where the interface implementation simply calls the type-specific methods?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Lets say in the future i decided i want to add in one more overload for all of those methods, I want to get a compile error instead of having to open up all of those files to check. Because the number of overload is sometimes > 10. The interface is not expected to be used other than verify all overloads are implemented

Answer (score 0):

I still am not sure I understand the question completely. However, for sure it is not possible to define a single interface where the interface members can take on different names depending on the implementing class.

Given that the underlying goal is one of maintainance — that is, to ensure a compile-time error if some class fails to implement all of the necessary methods — it seems to me that the closest one can come is to declare an interface with general-purpose method names, and then have each specific type implement that interface through delegation to the type-specific methods.

For example:

```
interface IOperator
{
    int Operation(int a, int b);
    float Operation(float a, float b);
    decimal Operation(decimal a, decimal b);
}

class Adder : IOperator
{
    public int Add(int a, int b){}
    public float Add(float a, float b){}
    public decimal Add(decimal a, decimal b){}

    public int Operation(int a, int b) { return Add(a, b); }
    public float Operation(float a, float b) { return Add(a, b); }
    public decimal Operation(decimal a, decimal b) { return Add(a, b); }
}


class Subber : IOperator
{
    public int Sub(int a, int b){}
    public float Sub(float a, float b){}
    public decimal Sub(decimal a, decimal b){}

    public int Operation(int a, int b) { return Sub(a, b); }
    public float Operation(float a, float b) { return Sub(a, b); }
    public decimal Operation(decimal a, decimal b) { return Sub(a, b); }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not actually *guarantee* that each type has implemented the type-specific methods in question. But it does require that each type implements the interface, and if you have developers on your team who would implement a new method in the interface by some means other than adding the corresponding type-specific method to the class and then calling it, you have bigger problems at hand. :)

It also seems unfortunate to me that this interface might not actually be used in the way that interfaces generally are: i.e. to support a polymorphic implementation of some specific contract. But maybe you'd find once you have something like this in place, it makes sense to go ahead and generalize other code.

For that matter, if you get to that point, maybe you'll find that it makes more sense to just stop writing these types with different method names in each type, given that across the different types the methods really are basically the same. :)

Comment: thx for the input. But the methods would have very different functionality. So its not easy to generalize them. Some classes might even have more than 1 sets of those overloads. And I really don't want to have one sets of duplicated method just to solve this problem.

Comment: You said the methods always have the same signature, so they are obviously related in some way. Your question is specifically about treating these groups of methods as if they are similar in some way, otherwise why insist they are all implemented by each class? Also, if some class might have more than 1 set of the overloads, then how in the world would you expect a single interface to catch whether that class has implemented the full set twice? It's not like a class can implement an interface more than once.

Comment: haven't try it, but I expect you can implement something like IComparable<int>, IComparable<string>. Correct me if im wrong. About the related in some way...its still ugly to see two methods doing exactly the same thing with the same parameter but different name..

Comment: You could implement two _different_ interfaces. But here you are specifically asking to avoid dealing with multiple interfaces. As already explained, even with a generic interface, you can't parameterize the _member_ names. Only the type(s) used in the interface. As for "ugly", yes...I agree. That's why I think the `Adder` and `Subber` classes (which each have a set of methods which do essentially the same thing) should not have class-specific method names, but instead both classes should implement methods having the same name. Bonus: if you do that, then a single interface suffices. :)

Comment: by avoid multiple interfaces I really mean multiple interface files. Cuz it will be the same thing if I have to go thru each interface and add in the overload manually where as if an interface with variable name would only require one line change. But I guess that's not possible

Comment: Why not implement the `Operation` interface methods explicitly? That would provide a neater API by publicly exposing methods with "proper" names whenever the concrete type is used, and fall back to using the more ambiguous method names whenever you upcast to the `IOperator` interface.